# Ошибки в файлах метаданных

Tags: ubuntu, метаданные

При использовании команды `sudo apt-get update` возникает ошибка

> Системный кэш AppStream обновлён, но найдены проблемы: Файлы метаданных содержат ошибки: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml

Погуглив, нашел решение, что проблема может быть в пакете appstream, а вернее в версии данного пакета.

Командой `sudo apt install appstream/xenial-backports` установил пакет версии 0.10.6-1, а далее выполнил команду `sudo appstreamcli refresh --force` и ее результат следующий

> Системный кэш AppStream обновлён, но найдены проблемы: Файлы метаданных содержат ошибки: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml

Answer (score 0):

выполнил следующее для решения:

1. sudo apt-get purge libappstream3
2. отключил

   ```
   #deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   #deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   ```

   но после обновления:

   ```
   $ sudo apt install appstream/xenial-backports
   ```

   до версии:

   ```
   $ appstreamcli --version
   ```

   AppStream CLI tool version: 0.10.6
3. `$ sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream`
4. выполнил:

   ```
   $ update Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack
   ```

   (в моем случае до последней 5.2.14) в т.ч. в гостевых
5. reboot

Результат:

```
$ sudo appstreamcli refresh --force --verbose
** (appstreamcli:3411): DEBUG: Added /usr/share/app-info/xmls to metadata search path.
** (appstreamcli:3411): DEBUG: Added /var/lib/app-info/yaml to metadata search path.
** (appstreamcli:3411): DEBUG: Added /var/cache/app-info/xmls to metadata search path.
** (appstreamcli:3411): DEBUG: Could not find DEP-11 data in APT directories.
** (appstreamcli:3411): DEBUG: Data did not change, no cache refresh needed.
** (appstreamcli:3411): DEBUG: Forcing refresh anyway.
** (appstreamcli:3411): DEBUG: Refreshing AppStream cache
** (appstreamcli:3411): DEBUG: Caches are up to date.
** (appstreamcli:3411): DEBUG: Using cached data.
** (appstreamcli:3411): DEBUG: Stemming language is: ru
Обновление кэша AppStream завершено успешно.

$ sudo apt update
```

все без ошибок!

Comment: `update Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack` после этой команды следующий ошибки `Команда 'update' не найдена, возможно вы имели в виду:
 Команда 'uupdate' из пакета 'devscripts' (main)
 Команда 'zupdate' из пакета 'zutils' (universe)
 Команда 'lupdate' из пакета 'qtchooser' (main)
 Команда 'pupdate' из пакета 'pbuilder-scripts' (universe)
 Команда 'xupdate' из пакета 'libxml-xupdate-libxml-perl' (universe)
update: команда не найдена
`

Comment: оригинальный мой ответ был подправлен администратором.

Comment: А в оригинале имелось ввиду обновите пакет Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack до соответствующей установленной версии самого VirtualBox (если он у Вас установлен, естественно, у меня сейчас 5.2.14) - это можно сделать прямо с графической оболчки  VirtualBox (Файл-проверить обновления или любым другим удобным способом обновления Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack)

Comment: + рекомендую (не помешает) не забудьте обновить  Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack как в самом host так и в gest обновить VirtualBox Gest Additions до соответствующей версии